# Split xlsx file into small files based on count of rows

Tags: r, dplyr, r-xlsx

I have a dataset with greater than `20000` rows which I can't import into `SharePoint` due to its total number rows upload limitation to `20000`. There are `17` columns and each of them have `6694` rows totaling to `113798`.

So, I want to split this `xlsx` file into smaller ones with total rows less than `20000`.

How can I do this?

Sample Data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = seq(1,6694), b = seq(1,6694), c = seq(1,6694),
                  d = seq(1,6694), e = seq(1,6694), f = seq(1,6694),
                  g = seq(1,6694), h = seq(1,6694), i = seq(1,6694),
                  k = seq(1,6694), l = seq(1,6694), m = seq(1,6694),
                  n = seq(1,6694), o = seq(1,6694), p = seq(1,6694),
                  q = seq(1,6694), replace = T)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `gl` to create a grouping index to `split` the big data into `list` of datasets with each having 20000 rows (if the whole data number of rows is not a multiple of 20000, the last list element will have the remaining number of rows)

```
n <- 20000
lst1 <- split(df2, as.integer(gl(nrow(df2), n, nrow(df2))))
```

Comment: thank you is `gl` part of `dplyr`?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy it is `base R`

Comment: This returns a list of `one tibble` with `6643` observations and `17` columns (`6643 * 17 = 113798)`.  I was expecting the list contain more `tibbles/datasets` though.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy The `n` used is 20000.  which is greater than 6643.  If you change the 'n' to 100 or so, it will have many splits